# Why does redefining a variable used in a generator give strange results?

Tags: python, generator

One of my friends asked me about this piece of code:

```
array = [1, 8, 15]
gen = (x for x in array if array.count(x) > 0)
array = [2, 8, 22]
print(list(gen))
```

The output:

```
[8]
```

Where did the other elements go?

Comment: Theory: The generator expression is evaluated up to the `for x in array` _but not further_ when it is created, _then_ `array` is redefined, _then_ the `count` check is evaluated on the new array.

Comment: Very interesting question. I am surprised that redefining the `array` has an impact on `gen`. Could lead to very hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @tobias_k That seems clearly true, as experiments on the second array show

Comment: While this is a duplicate, I believe it is a very valuable signpost based on the significantly different title (for SEO purposes) and the difference in explanations offered here vs the duplicate target. The fact it got such a high score in less than a week lends itself to that point, as well (a higher score than the dupe target got after 3 years).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer is in the PEP of the generator expressions, in particular the session [Early Binding vs Late biding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding):

> After much discussion, it was decided that the first (outermost)
> for-expression should be evaluated immediately and that the remaining
> expressions be evaluated when the generator is executed.

So basically the `array` in:

```
x for x in array
```

is evaluated using the original list `[1, 8, 15]` (i.e. immediately), while the other one:

```
if array.count(x) > 0
```

is evaluated when the generator is executed using:

```
print(list(gen))
```

at which point `array` refers to a new list `[2, 8, 22]`

Comment: Thank you, 1 more question, so list(gen), because the count is > 0, should be all of the elements od [2, 8, 22] right? but it is only 8.

Comment: @picklerick No, because the **for-loop** expression is evaluated with the first values of array, basically your code is equivalent to `list(x for x in [1, 8, 15] if [2, 8, 22].count(x) > 0)`

Comment: When the PEP says "the first (outermost) for-expression should be evaluated immediately", that's referring to `array`, not `x for x in array`. It's the expression the `for` iterates over. It doesn't make any sense to try to evaluate `x for x in` immediately.

Comment: Adding some print calls in the generator expression illuminates what's going on. [Live demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLLCpKrFSwVYg21FGw0FEwNI3lSk_NAwpoVCik5RcpVChk5iloFBRl5pVoJILUaioARaGszDSYVIWOApqsXnJ-KUhCU1PBTsFAkwuiDmi2JlcizE4jsJ1GRrFQ2ZzMYogSTQDI0i6u&lang=python)

Comment: `(x for x in iterable if <condition>)` can be rewritten as `tmp = iterable; (x for x in tmp if <condition>)` where `<condition>` *remains exactly the same as before* (and therefore does not have access to `tmp`).

Answer (score 12):

This becomes more clear if you give each array a unique name instead of re-binding `array`:

```
array1 = [1, 8, 15]
gen = (x for x in array1 if array2.count(x) > 0)
array2 = [2, 8, 22]
print(list(gen))
```

`x for x in array1` is evaluated at creation of the generator, but `if array2.count(x) > 0` is evaluated lazily, which is why you can already reference a yet undefined variable